# MySQL select distinct products from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join, distinct

MySQL select from 3 tables.

I have these 5 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `c_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (c_id)
);

CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `image_path` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (p_id)
);

CREATE TABLE `shop` (
  `s_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `province` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `suburb` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `streetNumber` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (s_id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE product_category (
p_id INT NOT NULL, 
c_id INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (p_id, c_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES Product(p_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES Category(c_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE product_shop (
p_id INT NOT NULL, 
s_id INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (p_id, s_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES product(p_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES shop(s_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Basically, a product can have many categories. A category can be assigned to many products. A shop can have many products. A product can be in many shops.

I would like to select all products where the category.c_id = 2, or category.c_id = 8 and the shop.s_id = 1 or shop.s_id = 2.

I am part way there with this:

```
select *
from product inner join product_category
on product_category.p_id=product.p_id
where (product_category.c_id=2)
or (product_category.c_id=8)
```

That gets all the products that have a category id of 2 and also products with a category id of 8, but it gets the same product twice if it has both category.c_id = 8 and category.c_id = 2.

Then I tried this to make it get unique products:

```
select DISTINCT(product.p_id) as product
from product inner join product_category
on product_category.p_id=product.p_id
where (product_category.c_id=2)
or (product_category.c_id=8)
```

Which is now distinct but does not show enough information about the product or category. I want to show as much information as possible in each row.

And the the next step is to only get the ones where the shop.s_id = 1 or shop.s_id = 2.

Can anyone help me get there or get closer? Thanks!

Comment: try `SELECT DISTINCT *` or `SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2 ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that you want to list all product information. If you dont want the products to repeat, you may use IN clause.

```
select p.*
from product p
where p.p_id in (select c.p_id from product_category c where c.c_id in (2,8))
  and p.p_id in (select s.p_id from product_shop s where s.s_id in (1,2))
```

Now, if you want all product data and list which categories and shops the product is related to, then you may use join and some very handy functions.

```
select p.p_id, p.`name`, p.brand, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.c_id SEPARATOR ', ') as categories, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.s_id SEPARATOR ', ') as shops
from product p inner join product_category c on p.p_id = c.p_id
               inner join product_shop s on p.p_id = s.p_id
where c.c_id in (2,8)
  and s.s_id in (1,2)
group by p.p_id, p.`name`, p.brand
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it displays this in the results row of one product, for categories and shops:
2, 8, 8, 2
1, 2, 1, 2` eg it has duplicate shops and categories for one product. I have posted a photo of the entries in my product_category table...Am I doing something wrong there, that is making it duplicate a single products' categories and shops?

Comment: This happens because the product is present in 2 shops and is related to 2 categories: 2 x 2 = 4 occurrences of the product. The solution is to add distinct on group_concat. See my edit on the answer.